# Including a Theorem in a section heading

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, theorems

Within my thesis I am attempting to number the studies listed throughout.

I have used a custom theorem style for this:

```
\newtheorem{study}{Study}
```

### First Issue

I then want to use this within my section headings, so that a section heading will look something like **5.2 Study 1. This is a test**

To achieve this, I am using the following code

```
\section[This is a test]{\protect\begin{study}This is a test\protect\end{study}}
```

This is both messy, and means that the Study number does not show up in my ToC. Is there a better way to include a theorem in a section heading?

### Second Issue

The theorem class puts breaks above and below the study, meaning the formatting of the heading has a line break after the section number, like so:

**5.2**

**Study 1.** This is a test

I have attempted to fix this by altering the theoremstyle, but has not worked. I want it to stop linebreaking, and to bold the text after Study 1. The code I am using to attempt that is below

```
\newtheoremstyle{study2}
  {0} % Space above
  {0} % Space below
  {} % Body font
  {} % Indent amount
  {\bfseries} % Theorem head font
  {:} % Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em} % Space after theorem head
  {} % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

  \theoremstyle{study2} \newtheorem{study}{Study}
```

How can I remove this line break, and how can I make the whole section heading bold?

Thank you very much in advance for any advice you can give.

### Working Example

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{study2}
  {0} % Space above
  {0} % Space below
  {} % Body font
  {} % Indent amount
  {\bfseries} % Theorem head font
  {:} % Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em} % Space after theorem head
  {} % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{study2} \newtheorem{study}{Study}


\begin{document}
\section[This is a test]{\protect\begin{study}This is a test\protect\end{study}}
\end{document}
```

### Desired Outcome Mock-up

[image: Desired Outcome mockup]

## SOLUTION

I have ended up using the following code:

```
 \newenvironment{study}
  {\enskip\refstepcounter{studyish}\textbf{Study~\thestudyish:\space}}% \begin{shortthm}
  {\enskip}% \end{shortthm}
\makeatother

 \newtheorem{studyish}{Study}
```

This fixes the line breaking problem. And allows for the Study number to be listed in the ToC. The new section headings look like this:

```
\section{\protect\begin{study}\label{study:FirstStudy}This is a test\protect\end{study}}
```

Comment: This is difficult to comprehend. Wouldn't it be enough to put the number of the study into the section heading? However, please give a minimal working example.

Comment: Could you post a graphic mock-up of what you want to achieve?

Comment: if all of your `study`s are used as section headings, and if you are using `amsthm` you can use `\swapnumbers` and use `[section]` as the controlling counter: `\swapnumbers \newtheorem[section]{study}{Study}`.  or if only some of them are at the section level, you could define a second version, say `secstudy` and tinker with counters to keep them in synch.

Comment: I've just added the working example, and the desired outcome mock-up. Hopefully that makes my question clearer. I am still unsure about the order of the studies, hence trying to use the Theorem solution. However, if there is no easy way of doing this, I will just hard code it and write it in by hand. I had just assumed there'd be a more "LaTeX-y" way of doing it. Thanks for input so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the wrong track. `;-)` Just setup a new counter and use it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{study}
\NewDocumentCommand{\study}{om}{%
  \refstepcounter{study}\IfValueT{#1}{\label{#1}}%
  \section{Study \thestudy: #2}%
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Title}

\section{A regular section}\label{sec:reg}

We'll see in study~\ref{st:first} (see section~\ref{sec:st})
that we're doing interesting things.

\study[st:first]{This is a test}\label{sec:st}

Whatever.

\end{document}
```

The label for the study number is given as optional argument to `\study`.

### Table of contents

[image]

### First page

[image]